# Getting contents with extract($variables), but the variables are undefined

Tags: php, arrays, variables, model-view-controller, extract

I haven't gotten the hang of the extract() function, and transferring variables. 
I have a method in a user controller where some variables are defined, and sent in an array to a view function in a parent controller, where the array is extracted. Then the view is required. But the variables turn out undefined. The array contents can be printed though.

Here is the user controller with a simplified profile function:

```
class User extends Controller{

    public function profile(){

         $profiledetails = $this->profiledetails();           
         $profilestatus = $this->profileStatus();            

         $this->view('profile', [$profiledetails, $profilestatus]);
}}
```

The variables are sent to the view function in parent Controller:

```
class Controller {
    public function view($view, $variables =[]){                    

    extract($variables);

    require_once './app/views/' . $view . '.php';
}}
```

And in the view, 'profile.php', the undefined variable error is shown. I thought that the "extract()" function would make $profiledetails and $profilestatus available as variables in the view. 
What am I doing wrong? Maybe I'm using the wrong type of array, or I should use "variabe variables" or something.. (in that case, how?).

Comment: `extract` wants an associative array.

Comment: It does, according to the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`extract` works with an **associative array**.

```
    $this->view('profile', 
      [
        'profiledetails' => $profiledetails, 
        'profilestatus' => $profilestatus
      ]);
```